# Trying to create an iam role in aws and getting an error on the assumeRolePolicyDocument

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-iam, federation

I am trying to create an IAM role in AWS for federated access and keep running into the same issue in python using boto or powershell using the cli.

Here is what I am trying to do with python.

```
import boto3

tpdoc = r'c:\folders\trustPolicy.json'

with open(tpdoc, 'r') as tpfile:
    data = tpfile.read()

client = boto3.client('iam')

response = client.create_role(
    RoleName="testrole",
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument=data
)
```

This referenced trustPolicy.json is constructed like this

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
               "SAML:aud": "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
            }
         },
         "Principal": {
            "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:saml-provider/myidp"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

When I run this code with that file I get the following error

> ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the
>   CreateRole operation: The specified value for assumeRolePolicyDocument
>   is invalid. It must contain only printable ASCII characters.

I have run the json through the aws json validator and it validates, and have also run the regex for allowable characters and it passes that as well. I have also tried copying an existing trust policy from a manually created role and using that content for my json file but that generates the same error as well.

Comment: Why are you regexp-quoting the filename?
`tpdoc = r'c:\folders\trustPolicy.json'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AssumeRolePolicyDocument` requires URL encoded contents of the file.
We can use `urllib.quote()` for this:

```
import boto3
import urllib

tpdoc = r'c:\folders\trustPolicy.json'

with open(tpdoc, 'r') as tpfile:
    data = tpfile.read()

encodedPolicy = urllib.quote(data)

client = boto3.client('iam')

response = client.create_role(
    RoleName="testrole",
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument=encodedPolicy
)
```